# How to block application network request using VPNService?

Tags: android, networking, android-vpn-service

I hope you all are well.

I have implement VPNService in My application. I have refer https://github.com/hexene/LocalVPN github code to create the VPN.

I want to know about the request/response,

How to know Which application send the request or which application receive the response using the VPNService.

I want to block some application request in VPNService.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please any one have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

If you just need a simple VpnService that blocks application traffic, without needing the extra feature of handling the packet tcp/udp headers that LocalVPN offers, you can just use ToyVPN (https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/ToyVpn) and use builder.addAllowedApplication or builder.addDisallowedApplication.

ToyVpnConnection.java:

```
   for (String packageName : mPackages) {
        try {
            if (mAllow) {
                builder.addAllowedApplication(packageName);
            } else {
                builder.addDisallowedApplication(packageName);
            }
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e){
            Log.w(getTag(), "Package not available: " + packageName, e);
        }
    }
```

However, if you need low level access to the packets like with LocalVPN, then I am unsure how to do this. If you find out, please post any tips on accomplishing this as I am currently trying to figure this out myself!